# I didn't get this joke from Dr. Octopus in Spider Man 2. Is there anything subtle in the language that I'm not picking up?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Dr. Octopus:

> Ladies and gentlemen. My wife Rosie and I would like to welcome you this afternoon. But first before we start, **has anybody lost a large roll of 20 dollar bills in a rubber band? Because we found the rubber band.**

Are there any linguistic subtleties going on?

I'd love to hear back from you people.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about understanding a joke that doesn't bear any special relationship to the *English* language above others

Comment: How can a cryptic joke written in English, for which an explanation is required, not bear any relationship to the English language?  Just asking.   I´m new here so forgive me if I have stumbled upon a fiefdom.

Comment: @BruceMurray because there's no subtlety in the words here. There's nothing that you can have missed ... ***as a non-English speaker***. The words mean exactly what they appear to mean. If you didn't understand the words at all, then you need a translation dictionary, not this forum. (I am also infrequent here, but I assume things like "what do the words *rubber band* mean?" are also off topic."

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I feel like the approach that would make SE feel like a more welcoming community would be to answer the question but then ask the asker what the stumbling point was, now that you’ve explained what they were looking to hear. Then you could close if they inform you that there was nothing about misunderstanding English that tripped them up. Otherwise it feels like you’re being closed-minded. Learning other languages is difficult. Especially English.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica As a non-English speaker, I am not familiar with American culture. I have never seen money carried in rolls of bills anywhere but in American movies. I do not know where else on the world this habit is considered normal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : instead of closing it, couldn't it be moved to the movies site?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I think this question is very much on topic. The OP presents a joke they didn't understand and asked if there's a subtlety in the language (that they don't get) which is behind the humor. The answer is no, there the humor is not based on the language. If the OP had just asked to explain the joke it would be off-topic. But currently it's phrased in a perfectly legitimate way IMO.

Comment: I propose a new site: "Explaining jokes". No, seriously, I sometimes don't get jokes either. It would be good to have someone explain them to me properly.

Comment: @Binyomin The initial comments above applied prior to my edit. Originally the question was just "here's the joke ... I don't get it?"

Comment: I can translate this almost word for word into bad Japanese and people will get it. 一万円の札束をなくした方がいらっしゃいますか。その輪ゴムが見つかれたよ。 Maybe the Japanese Stackexchange can explain the joke now.　Let's make that 帯封 or 帯テープ instead of 輪ゴム, since the custom is to bind wads of money with a paper tape.

Comment: Slovak: Stratil z vás niekto zväzok sto eurových bankoviek? Lebo gumička sa našla...

Comment: Just to reiterate: on this site it's ok to ask for an explanation for any joke, if you just remember to add "is this language-based" to the question?

Comment: @Moyli If the joke hinged on a linguistical quirk, or the double-meaning of a word in English, then it certainly would be on-topic (for example, *"How do you get [down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_relative_direction) from an Elephant?  You don't, you get [down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_feather) from a duck!"*).  However, OP can't necessarily know that until **after** the question is answered.

Comment: @Binyomin In brief, there is absolutely no "linguistic subtleties" going on. It's a joke that would work in any language, it's not exclusive to English.

Answer (score 37):

If they had found only the rubber band, how would they know it was once around a roll of money? Evidently, they found the money with the rubber band, but decided to keep the money.

Comment: Perfect analysis.

Comment: Good explanation. It might also be worth mentioning that the joke has the feel of vaudeville, or other comedians from the first half of the 20th century. I could easily imagine hearing it from the Marx Brothers or on The Goon Show (I'll leave it to you to read up on those if you're curious.) So as jokes go it's a bit corny and a bit dated -- kind of like what I see described these days as a "dad joke".

Comment: @BruceMurray I agree. This is a perfect analysis of the joke. But it has nothing whatsoever to do with the english language. You can crudely translate it into any other language and it'll still work exactly the same way.

Comment: It's definitely pure corn.

Comment: It's an old style of humor. It's a way to show that doc is old

Comment: Not just the rubber band, but also the information that they were 20 dollar bills.

Comment: In brief, there is absolutely no "linguistic subtleties" going on. It's a joke that would work in any language, it's not exclusive to the English language.